# スタックオーバーフローのアカウントを誤って2つ作ってしまった。統合できないか？

Tags: サポート, アカウント

表題のとおりです。

私個人の具体的なケースは

- userA

  - mailaddrress_a@example.com(google account)
- userB

  - mailaddress_b@example.com(stack exchange)
  - mailaddress_b@example.com(google account)
  - mailaddress_b@example.com(github acount)

という感じでuserAとuserBを統合したいです。
userBのログイン設定で`mailaddrress_a@example.com(google account)`を追加しようとすると、another userにログインし直しますか？となってしまいます。
なんとかする方法はあるでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts